Location and partition where template signals most differ for informed source separation
I state the problem in continuous time, yet of course it is discrete in practice, and time here stand for any ordinal axis (like frequency, scale). I observe a real signal $y$ which is supposed to be formed of a linear combination of $S$ source signals $x_s$, plus "noise" $n$, supposedly independent of the template signals, for $t\in [0,1]$. Therefore:
$$y(t) = \sum_{s=0}^{T-1} \lambda_s x_s(t) + n(t).$$
While sources overlap in time, each is thought to be dominant other the others (e.g. in amplitude) on preferential time intervals $\mathcal{T}_s$ that do not overlap pairwise (${i\neq j}$):
$$\mathcal{T}_i \cap \mathcal{T}_j=\emptyset$$
The generic question is: how could we find the most appropriate (which some metric) partition of $[0,1]$ in
:
$$ (\cup_s \mathcal{T}_s) \cup  \mathcal{T}_n = [0,1] $$
such that sources and noise look as different as possible, to be used as priors in optimization. I am aware that this question is ill-posed. I am looking for interesting references or pointers. For instance, are there metrics promoting  $x_i$ to dominate all others $x_j$ , $j \neq i$ on interval $\mathcal{T}_i$ in some sense.
One may add other constraints such as:

positivity,
support size, like $|\mathcal{T}_s|\geq C$.


This sounds a lot like source coding. The notation is a bit odd. Is the $\mathcal{T}$ made up of segments of $t$ or ($s$)? (i.e they denote which sources are "on"). In code division multiplexing for example, the receiver "tunes" in to the particular code used by the source of interest and considers all other sources as "noise".
